# 4 purchased CNFTs showing no asset image?

Tags: asset

asset1w2pqwj7cnv0dw40rtgv5vuzwa7jswcl24lkyw6

a0e859a7b29dbfc2b798ed720802fff406fe09b8e3c9a6b3affb7320

asset19s8v6a43k4ngrmy6wvccxqm08kuae4hfftt0ah

a0e859a7b29dbfc2b798ed720802fff406fe09b8e3c9a6b3affb7320

asset1pe24aeqhr0z9d0cq6pgrjf7dzegrdkgf0dv9af

84c0acb101c14416ad92859c429058871e201804468d5f353be31d71

asset1v34sp6q60z2c2u8fy6gh0su8hc0frghmtr0n9g

a0e859a7b29dbfc2b798ed720802fff406fe09b8e3c9a6b3affb7320

Policy IDs and fingerprints of the 4 CNFTs

I have bought 11 altogether and all the rest have no issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

where do you try to check and you find no asset image?

for all your assets i check on links below, using the asset ID next to pool.pm/asset_here :
https://pool.pm/asset1w2pqwj7cnv0dw40rtgv5vuzwa7jswcl24lkyw6

you can replace the "assetXXXX" with one of your address in your wallet, and you can see all your tokens in your wallet.

please let me know if you need something more,
TTS17